# Why does local struct with in-class initializer hide class' variables?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

Consider this code:

```cpp
class A
{
public:
  void f();

private:
  int foo;
};

void A::f( )
{
  struct S
  {
    int bar = 100;
  } s;

  s.bar = foo;
}
```

This won't compile with VS2013 giving C2327 and C2065 errors on the last line. However, if we delete the initializer or put struct declaration outside this will compile. Is this a bug or standard behavior?
**EDIT:** Just for the question being complete here are error messages:

> error C2327: 'A::foo' : is not a type name, static, or enumerator
>   error C2065: 'foo' : undeclared identifier

Comment: Woks with gcc and clang, and I can see no problem with it. You might need to get a better compiler.

Comment: Can you post the error messages that go along with the codes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is fine with VS2015 RC (ultimate). So VS 2013 has a bug for in class initialization.  The following code works for VS 2013

```
class A
{
public:
    void f();
private:
    int foo;
};

void A::f( )
{
    struct S
    {
        int bar;
        S(int b = 0) : bar{b} {}
    } s;

    s.bar = foo;
}
```

Comment: Right, so VS2013 has a bug with [its NSDMI support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#corelanguagetable) here. You should add that into your answer!

Answer (score 3):

Your code is perfectly legal. I would guess that MSVC has a problem with the "new" (i.e. C++11) "in class initializer" `int bar = 100;`.

Either use a more modern compiler or, if you insist on using MSVC 2013, either write C++98 or be prepared to get random compilation errors for correct code.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot.

```
class A
{
public:
    void f();

private:
    int foo;
};

void A::f( )
{
    struct S
    {
        int bar;
        S() { bar = 100; }
    } s;

    s.bar = foo;
}
```

EDIT: Just an FYI, you're trying to initialize a non-const static member in a local class.

Comment: Just an FYI, that's perfectly legal. It's not 1998 any more!!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Correct. With gcc 4.6.3 (2012) the original will throw an error. With gcc 4.9.2 and -std=c++11 flag, the original will compile correctly. My solution will work with both.

Comment: Actually, you may not even need that compiler flag.

Comment: IIRC you do until GCC 5